# Couldn't read RSA public key

Tags: delphi, encryption, openssl, rsa, firemonkey

I'm trying to read RSA public key, but **PEM_read_bio_RsaPublicKey** returns 0;
Same code for private key (**PEM_read_bio_RsaPrivateKey**) works ok.

```
function TForm1.ReadPublicKey(AFileName: TFileName): pRSA;
var
  keyfile: pBIO;
begin
  keyfile := BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
  BIO_read_filename(keyfile, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(AFileName)));
  result := PEM_read_bio_RsaPublicKey(keyfile, nil, nil, nil);
  if result = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to read public key. ' + GetErrorMessage);
end;
```

I'm using Delphi XE6 + OpenSSL libs 1.0.1i + Indy headers IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_static.

Private and public keys are generated with this command line...

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024 
openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem
```

...and look like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXgIBAAKBgQDyYSxGmR95H9tO2Be82RyFd0KzqCH64D0ssUtURbYw4qJTeKln
..cut..
fKcHkq+cl7KKVi+nocAO8sUzzzBFy9TlXbx8cgN/PIFwvw==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDyYSxGmR95H9tO2Be82RyFd0Kz
..cut..
WdCa/uFKyfIJHsQiuwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

It drives me crazy for 3 days now. If anyone knows what is the problem here or some other way to decrypt RSA string in MacOS/Firemonkey that was ecrypted online with PHP - please let me know! I tried some Lockbox version that I could install but it is not compatible with OpenSSL keys...

Updated: Error code is

```
error:0906D06C:lib(9):func(109):reason(108)
error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long while since I touched on any of this but I could never get PEM_read_bio_RsaPublicKey to work in Delphi. I tried for ages but in the end resorted to using something like the following for public keys:

```
function LoadPublicKey(const AFileName: string): PEVP_PKEY;
var
  bp: pBIO;
  utf8file: RawByteString;
begin
  // This is for SubjectPublicKeyInfo keys. ie those that
  // start -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
  utf8file := UTF8Encode(AFileName);   
  bp := BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
  BIO_read_filename(bp, PAnsiChar(utf8file));
  result := PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bp, nil, nil, nil);
  if result = nil then
    raise Exception.Create(sLoadPublicKeyFailed + GetSSLErrorMessage);
end;
```

This returns a PEVP_KEY which I could then use in the EVP* routines. It turned out easier to use this approach than to convert RSA keys into EVP keys with EVP_PKEY_assign(...) later on anyway.

I also used a similar routine for private keys with the PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey method.

Not sure if that will help in your case.

Comment: Yes, this must be the simplest way. I've made some changes to libeay32.pas (Indy doesn't know PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY, only PEM_read_bio_RsaPublicKey) and it's finally working! Thank you.

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot about libeay32. The version of Indy we have for that project is very old so we made our own version of libeay32.pas which delegated some of its content to IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders and then we added in the EVP_ routines and the missing PEM_ methods. It did involve quite a lot of reading through the OpenSSL source code!